# Content.js script never called to count table rows and refresh page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension with two buttons : Start and Stop. On click of start button the html page, should start refreshing after a particular timer, and on click of stop it should stop refreshing.

The HTML page has a table in it say with id myTable.So after every refresh, I want to have row count of this table.

To get this I did something like this :

First for pop up, I made popup.js

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("startbutton").onclick = function() {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({
        type: "table-row-count_start"
    });
}
document.getElementById("stopbutton").onclick = function() {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({
        type: "table-row-count_stop"
    });
}
}
```

In background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
switch(request.type) {
    case "table-row-count_start":
        alert("Refershing started");
        RefreshAndCount();
        break;
    case "table-row-count_stop":
        alert("Stop Refershing");
        break;
}
return true;
});

var RefreshAndCount = function(){
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {type: "table-row-count"});
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "Counting!"});
});
}
```

This will make call to content.js as we need to interact with DOM of HTML page. In this script I did something like this :

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
switch(message.type) {
    case "table-row-count":
        var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
        alert("Row count = " + x);
        var Refresh = confirm("Do you want to refresh the page?");
        if (Refresh)
        {
            setTimeout("location.reload(true);",5000);
        }
    break;
}
});
```

The script content.js is never called. I don't know why so. Please help.
Also it will  be refreshing only once, how to keep refershing after fixed timer.

Here is manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Refresher",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description" : "Refresh the site contents after a while",
"icons": { "32": "icon.jpg" },
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": { "32": "icon.jpg" },
    "default_title": "Refersher",
    "default_popup": "browseraction/popup.html"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
}]
}
```

Comment: Add `manifest.json` to the question.

Comment: @wOxxOm Added. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you've used a deprecated `chrome.tabs.getSelected` which returned the wrong tab with id `-1` so the message was never delivered and an error was displayed in the console.

Use [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query):

```
var RefreshAndCount = function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: "table-row-count"});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({tabId: tabs[0].id, text: "Counting!"});
    });
};
```

Also note how `setBadgeText` was used just for the specified tab.

N.B. [Always](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging),  [always](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) use the debugger to check what's wrong. Thus you can stop using `alert` and start using `console.log` or inspect/watch the variables in the debugger.

Comment: What about refershing till stop and not only once.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. Have you removed `alert` already and tried something like debugging?

Comment: Yes I did that. Now contetn.js is called but it gives this : Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null. What can be reason ?Assume I have only 1 table on my page, can something be done so that I dont need to hard code the id of table like i did here var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

Comment: Ahem... That's outside of the scope of the question but since it's some basic DOM manipulation stuff here you go: that page makes an `iframe` with the result inside so you need to look inside it for example like this `document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.querySelector('table')`. You should use the powerful DevTools Inspector and debugger to actually investigate the problems you encounter, don't guess blindly.

Comment: I am making a sepearte question for it. Please help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649407/refresh-after-a-timer-of-5000-seconds-and-print-the-alert